# Set up Serilog in a separate class and inherit from it?

Tags: c#, serilog

I am currently configuring Serilog in every class of my application.

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} " +
"[{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
 .CreateLogger();

 var log = Log.ForContext<Control>();
```

Is it possible to create Serilog settings in a separate class and inherit from it?

I am successfully creating settings in each class, is this correct or not? Creating a separate configuration, in my opinion, would improve the structure of the code.

It is configured once. In the classes add

```
var log = Log.ForContext<T>();
```

Comment: You usually configure Serilog once, at the startup of your application. This configuration can be done in a json file as well, so you can easily swap different configurations for different environments (eg. dev/staging/production). Then, instead of Configuring Serilog again, you just inject the ILogger<T> in each class that consumes it.

Comment: I'm ashamed, it turned out to be so simple.